# How to stream SHOUTcast radio streams on Chromecast receiver

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, shoutcast, internet-radio

We have a Android radio app which plays various live radio streams. It works pretty well with Google Chromecast as log the stream is a "normal" mp3 stream. The playback on Chromecast Styled Media Receiver is NOT working with SHOUTcast streams i.e `http://46.105.118.14:13500`.

After `mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(...)` I see in my Android LogCat a result `statuscode = 1`.

In Chrome debug console I see the following `Load metadata error`:

> **[673.080s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error**
>   *cast_receiver.js:18*
>
> **ib** *cast_receiver.js:18*
>
> **gb.Gb** *cast_receiver.js:18*
>
> **B.log** *cast_receiver.js:13*
>
> **E** *cast_receiver.js:15*
>
> **Z.pa** *cast_receiver.js:71*
>
> **Eb** *cast_receiver.js:23*
>
> **Cb** *cast_receiver.js:24*
>
> **(anonymous function)** *cast_receiver.js:21*

Is it possible to play SHOUTcast live streams with Google Chromecast (Styled Media Receiver or Custom Receiver)? If yes, can you give me some hints or point me to an example?

Comment: No answer so far... Looks like Chromecast does not support shoutcast streams at all. What a pity :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append a /; after the port of the stream url, so you get to the stream data i.e `http://46.105.118.14:13500/;`

I use the localcast android app with this trick to make my chromecast play SHOUTcast Radio.

Comment: Saved me! Thanks a lot!