# Chromecast wont play Shoutcast Stream

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, shoutcast

I have not been able to get the chromecast to connect and play a shoutcast stream.  It just returns a `SERVICE_MISSING` error.  I have seen a post about adding a `/` to the end of the url but this makes no difference for me.  I posted in the Winamp forums, they think it is related to the headers at the beginning of the stream.  I am currently using the Default Media Receiver.

Any tricks to get this working?

Comment: Shoutcast uses a PLS file, Chromecast does not directly support this, so you'll have to parse it inside your application before you cast it to the Chromecast.

Comment: Mdlc--thanks for the reply.  I already know the url of the stream.  It still will not play it.

Answer (score 1):

SHOUTcast servers use a non-standard status line in their response.  A normal status line:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

SHOUTcast status line:

```
ICY 200 OK
```

Because of this once difference, many clients fail to be able to handle the response from the server.  The solution is to simply not use SHOUTcast.  Use Icecast or another server that returns proper HTTP responses.

Once you do get the server compatibility issue solved, you may have another problem of codec compatibility.  I am not sure of the Chromecast codecs...  you may have to experiment in this area to see what is available to you.  Even if you do get the right codec, you have to have a compatible container.  For example, a lot of browsers support HE-AAC, but not when wrapped in the ADTS stream wrapper which is often used with SHOUTcast and Icecast servers.

Comment: Brad, Thanks for the reply.  I do not have the option to change server types.  joe

Comment: @Joeb Then, you do not have the option to get this working.  The problem is on the server.  You can't modify the client.  You have no choice but to fix the server.  If you can't fix it because you can't modify the server either, then at least you could put a server in to proxy the request, fixing the response along the way.  In any case, the problem must be fixed server side.

Answer (score 1):

Append the two characters `/;` after the port of the stream url, so you get to the stream data i.e `http://46.105.118.14:13500/;`

This worked for me with the Default Media Receiver. See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934513/how-to-stream-shoutcast-radio-streams-on-chromecast-receiver/24208569#24208569).

Comment: unfortunately this /; does not work for the streams I need to connect to.

Comment: Can you provide a url for testing?

Answer (score 0):

If you append `/;stream/1` it downloads for me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the Chromecast still will not play it.